# Use external dependency in Jira 7.x plugin

Tags: java, maven, osgi, jira, jira-plugin

With the SDK 6.3.10, I am trying to develop a plugin for Jira 7.x.

This plugin should use an external Java dependency named "maven-handling". I did the following:

First I added the dependency in the POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>some-company</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-handling</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I changed the import-package entry in the maven-jira-plugin to:

```
<Import-Package>org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional",          
 org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional",
 some-company.maven_handling*;version="0.0";resolution:="optional", * 
</Import-Package>
```

Still I get a classNotFound on the class I use from the some-company.maven_handling package. What did I miss?

Comment: Is the package `some-company.maven_handling*` correct? furthermore shouldn't OSGi versions always have three parts `0.0.0`? Do you use the tycho-maven-plugin to build this part of OSGi ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this plugin dependency is something that you wish to bundle with your plugin, and not something already included in Jira that you wish to access:

1. You only need to add `<Import-Package>` entries for packages that are defined elsewhere and made available to your plugin via OSGi. Since this dependency is not part of Jira itself and you are packaging it internally along with your plugin, you don't need to do this. Just remove it from the import list. I believe this will cure the problem.
2. You may also want to explicitly declare `<scope>compile</scope>` in the dependency in your pom to make it clear that you are intending to bundle this with your plugin (although this is the default scope, so it's optional).

Comment: Thank you. I am running into the exception 

2018-07-02 11:20:47,435 http-nio-2990-exec-4 ERROR anonymous 680x2x1 - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 /secure/DemoAction!default.jspa [c.a.j.web.dispatcher.JiraWebworkActionDispatcher] Exception thrown from action 'DemoAction!default', returning 404 
WebworkConfigurationNotFoundException{class=class webwork.config.XMLActionConfiguration, message='No such view mapping', name='DemoAction.actionRoles.actionRoles'}

which is do not understand at all.

Comment: This entry only occurs when I try to access the plugin after I added code that uses my external dependency.